# How can I remove from “previously installed apps” list in the PlayStore the applications that are already installed on my phone?

Tags: google-play-store

How can I remove from "previously installed apps" list in the PlayStore the applications that are already installed on my phone?

For example, the application anyconnect shows up in the "previously installed apps" list:

[image]

Even though it is already installed on my phone:

[image]

I use Android 9  on Samsung Galaxy S9 with PlayStore 17.8.14.

Comment: Also see: [Is there a way to clear your Google Play App history? (Not the search history)](/q/21841/16575) // [How to remove apps from “all downloaded” in Play Store](/q/20732/16575)